# Is aws_iam_policy_document's principal -> identifiers iteration possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to iterate `principal -> identifiers in Data Source: aws_iam_policy_document`?

> Terraform version: v0.11.15

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "kms_cmk_policy_document" {
      statement {
        sid = "Allow access for Key Administrators"
        actions = [
          "kms:Create*",
          "kms:Describe*",
          "kms:Enable*",
          "kms:List*",
          "kms:Put*",
          "kms:Update*",
          "kms:Revoke*",
          "kms:Disable*",
          "kms:Get*",
          "kms:Delete*",
          "kms:TagResource",
          "kms:UntagResource",
          "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
          "kms:CancelKeyDeletion",
        ]
        resources = ["*"]
        effect    = "Allow"
        principals {
          type        = "AWS"
          identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::accountName:role/${var.env_name}-role"] <--- NEED TO ITERATE WITH GIVEN "var.env_names" LIST
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: @Marcin : Moved to other tasks, but your solution partially works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate:

```
identifiers = [for env_name in var.env_name: "arn:aws:iam::accountName:role/${env_name}-role"]
```

for TF 0.11:

```
identifiers = "${formatlist("arn:aws:iam::accountName:role/%s-role", var.env_name)}"
```

Comment: Will the above statement work for Terraform version: v0.11.15. I'm getting following error: 

--------------------
Calling terraform init for Terraform v0.11.15:
Initializing modules...
- module.defaults
- module.test_kms_cmk
Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: module test_kms_cmk: Error parsing .terraform\modules\b82f8038eba34636a0c731d191f51d32\main.tf: At 56:22: unexpected token while parsing list: IDENT
--------------------

Comment: @Zeigeist I updated the answer. But TF 0.11 is very, very old and no longer even supported. You should seriously consider upgrading.